# Which AMD Driver am i using?

Tags: gpu-driver

I am running Ubuntu Mate 17.04 and have a RX580 Video Card.

I tried to install *amdgpu-pro* drivers using the following website which seems to install without any problems.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

I am trying to figure out if the driver is actually working or not and found 2 different commands but they give me different values

---

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
```

shows amdgpu-pro

---

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

shows driver=amdgpu

---

So am I using the *amdgpu* or the *amdgpu-pro*?

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro

Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  amdgpu-pro     17.10-414273 amd64        Meta package to install amdgpu Pr
```

---

```
sudo lshw -c video

    *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: e7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:cfe00000-cfffffff ioport:c000(size=256) memory:f9f80000-f9fbffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

Thanks in Advance
Eddie

Answer (score 1):

dpkg indicates that the drivers were installed, but lshw says you are using the old drivers.

using apt purge your original drivers. then reinstall the pro drivers.

finally reboot for the change to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for your reply... i have been reading a bunch and apparently the open source amdgpu drivers with mesa are very competitive so i am just going to stick with that for now

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
$ apt show amdgpu-pro
Package: amdgpu-pro
Version: 20.10-1048554
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Maintainer: Advanced Micro Devices (AMD) <slava.grigorev@amd.com>
Installed-Size: 17,4 kB
Depends: amdgpu (= 20.10-1048554), amdgpu-pro-core (= 20.10-1048554),
         libgl1-amdgpu-pro-glx (= 20.10-1048554), libegl1-amdgpu-pro (= 20.10-1048554),
         libgles2-amdgpu-pro (= 20.10-1048554), libglapi1-amdgpu-pro (= 20.10-1048554),
         libgl1-amdgpu-pro-ext (= 20.10-1048554), libgl1-amdgpu-pro-dri (= 20.10-1048554),
         libgl1-amdgpu-pro-appprofiles (= 20.10-1048554)
Download-Size: 5.328 B
APT-Sources: file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Packages
Description: Meta package to install amdgpu Pro components.
```

Comment: I didn't have that package, but this showed anything amd and gpu related: `sudo apt list|grep -i gpu|grep installed`